# How to load .env variables in a script that is not part of the Laravel life cycle?

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel it is possible to load variables from the `.env` file using `env('VARIABLE_NAME');`, however this will not work when I have a separate PHP script that is executed directly without the Laravel route.

I have a very specific PHP page that will run in an isolated scope and should not be part of Laravel. However the file will be located in the `public` directory of my Laravel project and I wish it to make use of Laravel tools, but the `env` function will not work.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

`env` will just load the given variable from `$_ENV` or `$_SERVER`. It's the `Dotenv` vendor class that will populate `$_ENV` with the contents of `.env` within the Laravel life-cycle. It's possible to load it manually using the `RepositoryBuilder` like so:

```php
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . "/../vendor/autoload.php";

use Dotenv\Dotenv;
use Dotenv\Repository\RepositoryBuilder;

// Manually load .env file:
$repositories = RepositoryBuilder::create()
    ->make();
$envs = Dotenv::create(
    $repositories,
    __DIR__ . '../../', // directory where the .env is located at
    '.env',
)->safeLoad();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <?php echo env('APP_NAME') ?>
</body>
</html>
```